# How to calculate requests per minute using Istio Prometheus metrics?

Tags: prometheus, istio, promql

I want to calculate requests per minute, aggregated by service name.

I'm using the following query but I'm not sure if it is correct.

```
sum(increase(istio_requests_total{destination_workload_namespace="falabella"}[1m])) by (destination_workload)
```

Comment: That seems correct. I would have said `60 * sum(rate(istio_requests_total{destination_workload_namespace="falabella"}[1m])) by (destination_workload) ` , but according to doc ( https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase ) it should be equivalent

Comment: I agree with Joel. @Joel Could you add it as an answer for more visibility?

Comment: Sure @jt97 , I just wrote it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks correct.
Another query would be:

```
60 * sum(rate(istio_requests_total{destination_workload_namespace="falabella"}[1m])) by (destination_workload)
```

As documented, they are equivalent: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase

Answer (score 1):

It is more technically correct to use `increase(istio_requests_total[1m])` instead of `60 * rate(istio_requests_total[1m])` for calculating the per-minute requests rate, since `istio_requests_total` is a counter with integer values (e.g. the total number of requests since the last counter reset). It is expected that `increase()` over the last minute must return integer values for integer counter, while `rate()` may return fractional values.

Unfortunately, Prometheus may return fractional results for `increase()` over integer counters because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. Additionally, `increase()` and `rate()` in Prometheus may miss counter increase for slow-changing counters - see [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) and [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for technical details. Prometheus developers are going to fix these issues - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit). In the mean time it is possible to use [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/), which solves these issues in [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) and [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) functions from the start.